# Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected but there is a ;

Tags: asp.net

Im a PHP guy and have inherited an aspx site with an issue. I have resolved one problem but now get the following error;

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 63:                      <%-- --%>
>   Line 64:                      <%
>   Line 65:       Dim MM.XSLTransform mm_xsl = new MM.XSLTransform();
>   Line 66:       mm_xsl.setXML("http://omfaxnews.wordpress.com/feed/");
>   Line 67:       mm_xsl.setXSL(Server.MapPath("wpxsl_fp.xsl"));
>
> Source File: c:\projects\www_omfax_co_uk\default_b.aspx    Line: 65
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET
>   Version:2.0.50727.3614

on this page 'http://www.omfax.co.uk/default_b.aspx'

The code I'm using is;

```
<%
Dim MM.XSLTransform mm_xsl = new MM.XSLTransform();
mm_xsl.setXML("http://omfaxnews.wordpress.com/feed/");
mm_xsl.setXSL(Server.MapPath("wpxsl_fp.xsl"));
Response.Write(mm_xsl.Transform());
%>
```

and as you can see there is a ';'. Any and all help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 8):

Are you using VB.NET or C#?

The `Dim` is from VB.NET, the `;` endings are from C# - you can't mix them like this.

The error message (CS1002) suggests that this is a C# site, so the code should be like this:

```
<%
MM.XSLTransform mm_xsl = new MM.XSLTransform();
mm_xsl.setXML("http://omfaxnews.wordpress.com/feed/");
mm_xsl.setXSL(Server.MapPath("wpxsl_fp.xsl"));
Response.Write(mm_xsl.Transform());
%>
```

I dropped the `Dim` statement.

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'MM.XSLTransform' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\06c030b8\b002f227\App_Web_mm_xsltransform.cs.4035b6f7.8m8kzylt.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\06c030b8\b002f227\assembly\dl3\9828914d\ccc37aba_4a32cb01\omfax.DLL'

Comment: @Robert Thain - stop IIS, clear out all of the files and folders in `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder, restart IIS and try again.